# “ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index”

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis

I am trying to Group by customers and price bin columns to calculate Sales/Orders
the code is

```
# Group by customers and price bins and calculate Sales/Order
df_by_customer_price = df_analysis.groupby(['CustomerID','price_equal_bin'],\
                    as_index=False).agg({'Sales':'sum','InvoiceNo':'nunique'})
df_by_customer_price['Sales/Order'] = df_by_customer_price['Sales']/\
                                df_by_customer_price['InvoiceNo']

df_by_customer_price.head(3)
```

the error produced is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-148-29dbd9251ee7> in <module>()
      1 # Group by customers and price bins and calculate Sales/Order
----> 2 df_by_customer_price = df_analysis.groupby(['CustomerID','price_equal_bin'],                    as_index=False).agg({'Sales':'sum','InvoiceNo':'nunique'})
      3 df_by_customer_price['Sales/Order'] = df_by_customer_price['Sales']/                                df_by_customer_price['InvoiceNo']
      4 
      5 df_by_customer_price.head(3)

4 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py in sanitize_index(data, index)
    746     if len(data) != len(index):
    747         raise ValueError(
--> 748             "Length of values "
    749             f"({len(data)}) "
    750             "does not match length of index "

ValueError: Length of values (33647) does not match length of index (43240)
```

Here is an attachment of my [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1J-03B7pJ6g1kjWA68DhIdjH3jYmHtTcK?usp=sharing) file so that you can see what i am doing trying to do

Comment: This question is unclear. Please add more information. Also the google colab link requires permissions, please allow permissions or edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to run the code, but here's something you can try.

```
df_by_customer_price = df_analysis.groupby(['CustomerID','price_equal_bin'],\
                    as_index=False).agg({'Sales':'sum','InvoiceNo':'nunique'})
df_by_customer_price.reset_index(inplace = True)
df_by_customer_price['Sales/Order'] = df_by_customer_price['Sales']/
                                df_by_customer_price['InvoiceNo']
```

Comment: Its not working its producing the same error Actually I am trying to implement this project https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/linh279/customers_segment/blob/master/Clustering_Retail_Data.ipynb can you please have a look once